# How to measure F1 score and NMI for clustering task?

Tags: clustering, k-means, model-evaluations, mutual-information

I see the authors of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07464.pdf) are measuring F1 and NMI scores to measure the clustering quality. However, I don't understand the algorithm of how they actually measure it. See the Evaluation Section.

Although I have looked at the [code](https://github.com/rksltnl/Deep-Metric-Learning-CVPR16/tree/master/code/evaluation), I am not sure about the actual algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Use the original papers, and books, on F1 and NMI.

There is little reason to only use a 2016 arxiv (non-reviewed) paper that *uses* them, because they have been introduced long before.

I don't see F1 mentioned anywhere in the paper,and it would be an uncommon choice for clustering (see literature for details).

Comment: [N-Pair Loss](http://www.nec-labs.com/uploads/images/Department-Images/MediaAnalytics/papers/nips16_npairmetriclearning.pdf)  [facility location problem](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Song_Deep_Metric_Learning_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf) [Lifted structure loss](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06452.pdf) are also using similar kind of evaluation measures. That is the only reason I wanted to know.

Comment: Yes, these are *standard*. Use a textbook, and/or the original sources, not some 2016 preprint that just uses them.